# Unable to run npm install in new cloned project in new windows 10 machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Unable to run npm install in new cloned project in new windows 10 machine. please help me.

```
  D:\folderpath\folderpath>npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated babel@6.23.0: In 6.x, the babel package has been deprecated in favor of babel-cli. Check https://opencollective.com/babel to support the Babel maintainers
    npm WARN deprecated @types/googlemaps@3.30.18: Types for the Google Maps browser API have m oved to @types/google.maps. Note: these types are not for the googlemaps npm package, which is a Node API.
    npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    npm WARN deprecated react-intercom@1.0.15: Package no longer maintained. Use at your own risk.
    npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    npm WARN deprecated react-load-script@0.0.6: abandoned and unmaintained
    npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
    npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.
    npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
    npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
    npm WARN deprecated axios@0.19.2: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
    npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
    npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
    npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
    npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
    npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
    npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
    npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
    npm WARN deprecated @material-ui/core@4.12.3: You can now upgrade to @mui/material. See the guide: https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
    npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild
--verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'D:\\folderpath\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
    npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
    npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
    npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
    npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
    npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
    npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
    npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
    npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\folderpath\\folderpath\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\folderpath\folderpath\node_modules\node-sass
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
    
 

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:    npm ERR!    C:\Users\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-31T22_27_20_545Z-debug-0.log
```

- npm --version 8.4.0
- node -v v16.13.2

Comment: Looks like node-sass is your issue. I would look at [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962027/i-get-an-error-related-to-gyp-when-i-try-to-do-npm-install)

Answer (score 0):

> check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH

need install python2 and add PATH